# Nginx - How to receive encryption logs and decrypt them

Tags: encryption, nginx

I have a Ubuntu log server with installed nginx that listens on port 514 and gets logs from FWs. These logs are further send to syslog-ng and logstash (also installed on the same Ubuntu server, the logstash parses the logs so I need them decrypted on the Ubuntu) and onto their way to a cloud SIEM using https POST API call.

Currently the logs are sent to me unencrypted but I'd like to receive them encrypted and nginx would need to decrypt them and continue with redirection to whatever. Or is more like obtaining a CA certificate, if this is the case I somehow have dificulties doing this with OpenSSL, so any help is welcomed here as well.

Could you please point me in the right direction here, what needs to be done so that I can receive encrypted logs and decrypt them? Is it some sort of generating key pairs and share the public key with the guys who send the logs to me so that they sign them with this key and the logs are automatically decrypted by nginx since i have the private key?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to transfer files via HTTPS?

Comment: no, the way I see it is TCP with SSL/TLS.